# Get next five saturday date of the last month

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.3, php-5.6, php-7.2

I need next 5 saturday from the last month. 
eg. current date is 07-04-2018 so I need 5 saturday of the last month.
output- 03-03-18, 10-03-18, 17-03-18, 24-03-18, 31-03-18.
I can get it by using below but this is completely hardcoded.
How can i apply here loop to get next five saturday of the last month?

```
$firstSat= date("dmy", strtotime("first saturday of last month"));
$secondSat= date("dmy", strtotime("second saturday of last month"));
$thirdSat= date("dmy", strtotime("third saturday of last month"));
$forthSat= date("dmy", strtotime("fourth saturday of last month"));
$fifthSat= date("dmy", strtotime("fifth saturday of last month"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new DateTime()`

```
$y = 2018;
$m = 3;

$sat1 = new DateTime("first saturday of $y-$m");
$sat2 = new DateTime("second saturday of $y-$m");
$sat3 = new DateTime("third saturday of $y-$m");
$sat4 = new DateTime("fourth saturday of $y-$m");
$sat5 = new DateTime("fifth saturday of $y-$m");

echo $sat1->format('dmy') . "<br />";
echo $sat2->format('dmy') . "<br />";
echo $sat3->format('dmy') . "<br />";
echo $sat4->format('dmy') . "<br />";
echo $sat5->format('dmy') . "<br />";
```

This will result to:

```
030318
100318
170318
240318
310318
```

---

Getting all Saturdays of a month

```
$date = "03/17/18"; //Date on mm/dd/yy format

$start = new DateTime($date);
$end = new DateTime($date);
$end = $end->add(new DateInterval('P40D'));

$satPeriod = new DatePeriod (
    $start,
    DateInterval::createFromDateString('next saturday'),
    $end
);

foreach ($satPeriod as $saturday) {
    echo $saturday->format("dmy");
    echo "<br />";
}
```

This will result to:

```
170318
240318
310318
070418
140418
```

Comment: Thanks Eddie. I don't want to write 5 lines for 5 saturday. I just want If I get the 1st saturday of the last month then next 4 saturday from the 1st saturday of the last month.

Comment: @DevendraVastrakar I added new update. This will echo all Saturdays on the month

Comment: I thing one last saturday is not coming(310318). Is there any way to get next saturday of the given date. Eg. **next saturday of 03-03-2018**

Comment: Thanks. What about if I have date like 17-03-18 and want next 5 saturday date. eg. 24-03-18, 31-03-18, 07-04-18, 14-04-18,21-04-18

Comment: @DevendraVastrakar Updated answer, this answer will give 5-6 Saturdays. Just remove the exceeding saturdays